# Pythonic way to print list items

Tags: python, list, printing, list-comprehension

I would like to know if there is a better way to print all objects in a Python list than this :

```
myList = [Person("Foo"), Person("Bar")]
print("\n".join(map(str, myList)))
Foo
Bar
```

I read this way is not really good :

```
myList = [Person("Foo"), Person("Bar")]
for p in myList:
    print(p)
```

Isn't there something like :

```
print(p) for p in myList
```

If not, my question is... why ? If we can do this kind of stuff with comprehensive lists, why not as a simple statement outside a list ?

Comment: Where did you get the impression that using `for p in myList` was "not really good" ?

Comment: @JonClements : http://chrisarndt.de/talks/rupy/2008/output/slides.html

Comment: @Guillaume You sure about that? There's a slide that says "**Use `in` where possible**. Good: `for key in d: print key`". Link is dead though so here's [an archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20121027131509/http://chrisarndt.de/talks/rupy/2008/output/slides.html).

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 3:

```
print(*myList, sep='\n')
```

This is a kind of *unpacking*. Details in the Python tutorial: [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)

You can get the same behavior on Python 2 using `from __future__ import print_function`.

With the print statement on Python 2 you will need iteration of some kind. Regarding your question about `print(p) for p in myList` not working, you can just use the following which does the same thing and is still simple:

```
for p in myList:
    print p
```

For a solution that uses `'\n'.join()`, I prefer list comprehensions and generators over `map()` so I would probably use the following:

```
print '\n'.join(str(p) for p in myList)
```

Comment: in python 2x using map is slightly faster than using join on a list comprehension.

Comment: Why the downvote, is it really due to the speed difference between `map()` and a generator?  [Python's creator also happens to prefer comprehensions and generators over `map()`](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I am familiar with that post from GVR which was his way of saying, back then, how future versions of python were not going to include it but, they ended up staying.

Comment: They did stay in Python 3.x, but his point in that article is that `[F(x) for x in S]` is more clear than `map(F, S)`.  Performance is not addressed there, but I would expect the speed difference to be negligible.  Anyway I was just confused about the downvote, sorry I assumed it was you!

Comment: Can this be combined with other strings in a single print statement?

Comment: @EliezerMiron Yes, for example, `print('baz', *myList, 'qux', sep='-')` -> `baz-foo-bar-qux`. (The ability to have positional arguments after a starred argument was added in Python 3.5 per [the docs on calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=unpacking#calls).)

Answer (score 30):

I use this all the time:

```
l = [1,2,3,7] 
print "".join([str(x) for x in l])
```

Comment: To add `format()`, replace the `str(x)` with a format string: `print " ".join(["{:02d}".format(x) for x in l])`

Answer (score 8):

`[print(a) for a in list]` will give a bunch of None types at the end though it prints out all the items

Comment: this is what I've been using so far. It's one line, very clear and expresive, but linter complaints "Expression is assigned to nothing"

Comment: If you want to troll the linter, you can make a separate function that prints it out and returns some stupid value and call that function in the list comprehension

Comment: [Don't use a list comprehension for side effects](/a/5753614/4518341) for exactly the reason you mentioned: it creates a bunch of junk as well. Just use a plain for-loop, like `for a in list: print(a)`

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.*:

If you overload the function __str__() for your Person class, you can omit the part with map(str, ...). Another way for this is creating a function, just like you wrote:

```
def write_list(lst):
    for item in lst:
        print str(item) 

...

write_list(MyList)
```

There is in Python 3.* the argument **sep** for the print() function. Take a look at documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding @lucasg's answer (inspired by the comment it received):

To get a ***formatted*** list output, you can do something along these lines:

```
l = [1,2,5]
print ", ".join('%02d'%x for x in l)

01, 02, 05
```

Now the `", "` provides the separator (only between items, not at the end) and the formatting string `'02d'`combined with `%x` gives a formatted string for each item `x` - in this case, formatted as an integer with two digits, left-filled with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

To display each content, I use:

```
mylist = ['foo', 'bar']
indexval = 0
for i in range(len(mylist)):     
    print(mylist[indexval])
    indexval += 1
```

Example of using in a function:

```
def showAll(listname, startat):
    indexval = startat
    try:
        for i in range(len(mylist)):
            print(mylist[indexval])
            indexval = indexval + 1
    except IndexError:
        print('That index value you gave is out of range.')
```

Comment: Just as a note, please check the answer above you. You use a range, which provides an index value, i, yet you use another variable, indexval, as your index?? You're fighting against the simplicity of python. for val in my_list: print val does the same as what you have

Comment: That function is atrocious. If you pass in `mylist` and specify *any* `startat` value other than 0, -1, or -2, it errors. Plus, it seems glaringly obvious that `startat` should default to 0, and that there's no need for `indexval` (like BretD says) when you can just do `mylist[i+startat]` instead. For printing a list starting from a certain point, you can simply use slicing, like `for val in my_list[startval:]: print(val)`

Comment: Also, `listname` represents the list itself, not the name of the list (like a string), so call it something else. And it's not even used in the function body; `mylist` is instead.

Comment: (Not trying to be mean, just trying to tell people who maybe don't know Python that this code is bad, so don't use it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most convenient if you just want to see the content in the list:

```
myList = ['foo', 'bar']
print('myList is %s' % myList)
```

Simple, easy to read and can be used together with format string.

Comment: Old printf-style formatting is no longer recommended (see the note [here in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)). It's not even necessary in this case: `print('myList is', myList)`. Alternatively, newer f-strings let you get the variable name and value together more easily: `print(f'{myList = }')` -> `myList = ['foo', 'bar']`

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a password generator and although I'm VERY NEW to python, I whipped this up as a way to display all items in a list (with small edits to fit your needs...

```
x = 0
up = 0
passwordText = ""
password = []
userInput = int(input("Enter how many characters you want your password to be: "))
print("\n\n\n") # spacing

while x <= (userInput - 1): #loops as many times as the user inputs above
    password.extend([choice(groups.characters)]) #adds random character from groups file that has all lower/uppercase letters and all numbers
    x = x+1 #adds 1 to x w/o using x ++1 as I get many errors w/ that
    passwordText = passwordText + password[up]
    up = up+1 # same as x increase


print(passwordText)
```

Like I said, IM VERY NEW to Python and I'm sure this is way to clunky for a expert, but I'm just here for another example

Comment: This doesn't even print a list, it prints a string. There *is* a list involved in the code, but it's not relevant to the printing part.

Answer (score 0):

To print each element of a given list using a single line code

```
 for i in result: print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing this: this will also print it as a string

```py
print(''.join([p for p in myList]))
```

or if you want to a make it print a newline every time it prints something

```py
print(''.join([p+'\n' for p in myList]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are fine with your list being printed [1,2,3], then an easy way in Python3 is:

```
mylist=[1,2,3,'lorem','ipsum','dolor','sit','amet']

print(f"There are {len(mylist):d} items in this lorem list: {mylist}")
```

Running this produces the following output:

> There are 8 items in this lorem list: [1, 2, 3, 'lorem', 'ipsum',
> 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']

Answer (score -1):

OP's question is: *does something like following exists, if not then why*

```
print(p) for p in myList # doesn't work, OP's intuition
```

answer is, it **does exist** which is:

```
[p for p in myList] #works perfectly
```

Basically, use `[]` for list comprehension and get rid of `print` to avoiding printing `None`. To see why `print` prints `None` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193205/list-comprehension-returning-values-plus-none-none-none-why)

Answer (score -1):

You can also make use of the len() function and identify the length of the list to print the elements as shown in the below example:

```
sample_list = ['Python', 'is', 'Easy']

for i in range(0, len(sample_list)):

      print(sample_list[i])
```

Reference : https://favtutor.com/blogs/print-list-python