# List comprehension returning values plus [None, None, None], why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im studying comprehensions. I get the print(x) part (i think. It prints the value of x that passes the 'in' test) but why is it also returning a list of None afterward?

```
>>> g
['a', 'x', 'p']

>>> [print(x) for x in g]
a
x
p
[None, None, None] #whats this?
```

Comment: That is the return value from `print()`.

Comment: I dont quite understand... I thought print was returning a thenn x then p

Comment: i don't think [print(x) for x in g] evaluates anything if you use python 2.7

Comment: python 3 sorry forgot to say that

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the correct way to do this is not to use a comprehension i.e. `for x in g: print(x)`.

Comment: @AndyHayden, curious if you could explain more. When/why should I use the loop over the list comprehension?

Comment: "I thought print was returning a then x then p" - no; it is **displaying** those letters. Returning from a function has **nothing to do with that**. A call to a function is an *expression*, and `return` tells *what the result is*. Just like how, if you compute `1 + 2 + 3`, the result from `1 + 2` does not get displayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use a list comprehension to print the items in the list, and then the list itself is printed. Try assigning the list to a variable instead.

```
>>> g
['a', 'x', 'p']

>>> x = [print(x) for x in g]
a
x
p
#
```

Now the list is in x and isnt printed. The list is still there...

```
>>> print(x)
[None, None, None]
>>> x
[None, None, None]
```

Comment: merely assigning the result to a variable causes the Nones to go away... head exploding. Tested this and youre right.

Comment: The Nones are still there - they are just in variable 'x'. When you are in the interpreter, anything that is not assigned to a variable is printed. Your head can unexplode.

Comment: -1.  I think the correct advice is to do away with the list comprehension.  Assignment merely hides the error by polluting the namespace with an unnecessary name.

Answer (score 22):

`print` is a function (in Python3). It prints something to the screen, but *returns* None.

In Python2, `print` is a statement. `[print(x) for x in g]` would have raised a SyntaxError since only expressions, not statements, can be used in list comprehensions. A function call is an expression, which is why it is allowed in Python3. But as you can see, it is not very useful to use `print` in a list comprehension, even if it is allowed.

Comment: I'd put it a little more explicitly.  If you don't need a list, then don't use a list comprehension.  Using a list comprehension merely for its side effects is unpythonic.

Comment: Right. And it is "unpythonic" because it builds a (potentially huge) list which consumes memory but is never used.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I've seen some pretty neat ways which leverage using *generator* expressions merely for side-effects (and I think this can be pythonic), but they wouldn't work with a print (so obviously this is not such an example).

Answer (score 2):

```
[print(x) for x in g]
```

is equivalent to:

```
l = []
for i in g:
    l.append(print(i))
return l
```

Print does the printing stuff, so you see the a, x and p, but it return `None` so the list you get in the end is [None, None, None]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are conflating a list comprehension with [str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method.

A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) *always* produces a *new list*. Three ways list may be produced that is the same as `g`

```
>>> [x for x in 'axp']
['a', 'x', 'p']
>>> [x[0] for x in ['alpha', 'xray', 'papa']]
['a', 'x', 'p']
>>> list('axp')
['a', 'x', 'p']
```

Since `g` is already strings, you use join to produce a single string to print it:

```
>>> g=['a', 'x', 'p']
>>> ''.join(g)
'axp'
```

To print it, just use join with the separator desired:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(g))
a
x
p
```

You would need to use a comprehension if the elements of the list are not compatible with join by being strings:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3]
>>> '\n'.join(li)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
>>> print('\n'.join(str(e) for e in li))
1
2
3
```