# Why does this give [None]*5?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

on running

```
[print(n) for n in range(5)]
```

it gives

```
0
1
2
3
4
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`. The result of the list comprehension is the sequence of values returned by your function.

Comment: Also: [List comprehension returning values plus [None, None, None\], why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193205/list-comprehension-returning-values-plus-none-none-none-why)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: ok, I got it, it is like print([print(0), print(1), print(2), print(3), print(4)])

Comment: Please don't use a list comp unless you actually want a list. See [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5753597/4014959)

Answer (score 3):

The list comprehension effectively does this:

```
L = []
for n in range(5):
    r = print(n)
    L.append(r)
print(L)
```

`print(...)` has the side-effect of displaying the arguments to screen, but has a return value of `None`. This is why a list of `None`s is created. However, when you run this in the shell, you're asking to see the list-comp'd list... which is five `None`s

Answer (score 2):

`print()` doesn't return anything. So, when you call
`[print(n) for n in range(5)]`, it's printing `n` 5 times *as it creates an array of 5 `None`s*.

Answer (score 2):

`print(n)` returns None so the resulting list from the list comprehension will be [None]*5

Answer (score 2):

`print` doesn't return its argument; it writes it to the file handle used for standard output and returns `None`. The expected list is produced by `[n for n in range(5)]`.

Interactive interpreters confuse the issue a bit because they always print the value of an expression to standard output after evaluating it. In your example, standard output gets 0 through 4 written by the evaluation of the calls to `print`, then the interpreter itself prints the string representation of the resulting list to standard output as well. If you put the same code in a file and run it *outside* an interactive interpreter, you'll see only the first 5 lines, but not the resulting list.