# Iterating over a list value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a parent class:

```
class Animal(object):

    animalFoods = {'Elephant': ['Grass', 'Trees'], 'Turtle': 'Fish'}

    def animal_food(self):
        foods = Animal.animalFoods[self.__class__.__name__]
        for food in foods:
            return food
```

Then I have a subclass:

```
class Elephant(Animal):
    pass
```

I create an object:

```
Dumbo = Elephant()
```

And try to print out its food choice:

```
>>> print(Dumbo.animal_food())
Grass
```

I expect it to print out

```
Grass
Trees
```

I see how it is working by finding the key in the `animalFoods` dictionary, but I am not sure why it is not returning both values in the value list.

Pointers towards additional reading are appreciated over just providing a quick and dirty answer, as this is my first time working with dictionaries beyond single values.

Comment: Since you have already have the list of food `foods = Animal.animalFoods[self.__class__.__name__]`, there is no need to iterate that list. Besides, if you want to print items in list, you could have a look at [Pythonic way to print list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769246/pythonic-way-to-print-list-items). Or if you want to iterate the list, the reason that you stop at the half way is, as pointed by @Alex, is terminated by 'return'

Comment: Thank you for the additional helpful link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return food` will immediately end execution of your `animal_food`; it will not attempt to complete the loop. If you wanted to get very fancy, you could use `yield food` to turn the method into a generator, but probably for this example you just want to replace the method body completely:

```
def animal_food(self):
    return Animal.animalFoods[self.__class__.__name__]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see here:

```
foods = Animal.animalFoods[self.__class__.__name__]
for food in foods:
    return food
```

for `foods`, it is right, which is `['Grass', 'Trees']`.

But you do `for food in foods: return food`. the `return` just return the `for loop`, so you get one result.

Answer (score 0):

Once a function or a method returns a value the for loop execution will halt.

If you merely wanted to print the items you could add the `print` statement to the class method `animal_food()` like this:

```
def animal_food(self):
  foods = Animal.animalFoods[self.__class__.__name__]
  for food in foods:
    print food
```

Then, calling `Dumbo.animal_food()` would print both answers.