# How to print multiple times from a list in Python

Tags: python

Have a school assignment and I have everything done. I was revising my code and realized the last part should be cleaned up a bit, but I don't know how. I want to print multiple items from a list so that I don't have to have multiple print lines. They didn't tell me how in the lesson, so I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!

I want to clean up the print lines and convert them to one.

```
def main():

    favoritethingsList = ["1  Film Production", "2  Photography", "3  Programming", "4  Mountain Biking", "5  Surfing"]

    print(favoritethingsList[0])
    print(favoritethingsList[1])
    print(favoritethingsList[2])
    print(favoritethingsList[3])
    print(favoritethingsList[4])

main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at the string `join` function....

Comment: `print(', '.join(favoritethingsList))`

Comment: For future reference, this sort of question belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). [so] is for broken code :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769246/pythonic-way-to-print-list-items

Comment: @TemporalWolf Stack Overflow is for *specific questions*, this is a specific question. On Code Review this would get closed as example code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I appreciate all of you taking the time to answer. I will make sure to ask on code review from now on. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to do this:

```
def main():
    favoritethingsList = ["1  Film Production", "2  Photography", "3  Programming", "4  Mountain Biking", "5  Surfing"]
    for line in favoritethingsList: print(line)

main()
```

In case you want to print all of the contents of the list in a single line, use

```
print(", ".join(favoritethingsList))
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, the code looks much better and it can fit inside my document. Thanks!