# Pulling from a list array dic python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have litterly read every post I could find on pulling keys from this array. I can get the the array to print the dic but i cant seem to pull the keys. I need it to print first and last name. Learning python but cant seem to get this.

```
students = [
     {'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'},
     {'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Rosales'},
     {'first_name' : 'Mark', 'last_name' : 'Guillen'},
     {'first_name' : 'KB', 'last_name' : 'Tonel'}
]


for i in students:


    first = [students[i].get('first_name') in students.values()] + [students[i].get('last_name') in students.values()]
    second= [students[i].get('first_name') in students.values()] + [students[i].get('last_name') in students.values()]
    third=  [students[i].get('first_name') in students.values()] + [students[i].get('last_name') in students.values()]
    four=   [students[i].get('first_name') in students.values()] + [students[i].get('last_name') in students.values()]



    print first, second, third, fourth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looping through array, your `i` is the element already

```
for i in students:
  print([i['first_name'], i['last_name']])
```

Comment: This works but i cant post a yes for 7 min. Is there a way to make it just post the names and not the ['Michael', 'Jordan']
['John', 'Rosales']
['Mark', 'Guillen']
['KB', 'Tonel']

Comment: @DavidHollenbeck That is a separate question. Please ask a new question instead (or better yet, search for a previously asked one because it has for sure been answered before, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769246/pythonic-way-to-print-list-items)).

Comment: Yes it can replace to `print "{} {}\n".format([i['first_name'], i['last_name'])`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, it looks like you just want to store the first and last name in the string respectively.

```
students = [
    {'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'},
    {'first_name' : 'John', 'last_name' : 'Rosales'},
    {'first_name' : 'Mark', 'last_name' : 'Guillen'},
    {'first_name' : 'KB', 'last_name' : 'Tonel'}
]
first = students[0]["first_name"] + " " + students[0]["last_name"]
second = students[1]["first_name"] + " " + students[1]["last_name"]
third = students[2]["first_name"] + " " + students[2]["last_name"]
fourth = students[2]["first_name"] + " " + students[2]["last_name"]
print first, second, third, fourth
```

and gives the output

```
Michael Jordan John Rosales Mark Guillen Mark Guillen
```

This will store the first and last name of the values of the dictionary within the variable.

I had to use list notation to get the index of the dictionary that I wanted then access the value with the key. If you look at the first line.

`students[0]["first_name"]`

The array notation `[0]` is referring to `{'first_name':  'Michael', 'last_name' : 'Jordan'}` this dictionary. The ["first_name"] allows me to access the key_value sorted at the key. in our case `'Michael'`.