# Print a python list in a word format like is one string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just need to print:

```
0123456789
```

Instead of this, independent of the list size:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Here is the code example:

```
c = []

for x in range(0, 10):
    c.append(x)

print c
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to print list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769246/pythonic-way-to-print-list-items)

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join your elements together, but they need to be strings.

If you have integers, use [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) first.

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> ''.join(map(str, l))
'0123456789'
```

Without `map`, you could also write :

```
>>> ''.join(str(i) for i in range(10))
'0123456789'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
c = []

for x in range(0, 10):
    c.append(str(x))

print ''.join(c)
```