# how can i remove bracket in list with float data

Tags: python, list

i have a list of float and i want place in a container and get the values without brackets

```
tt1= [102, 0.5, 0.591, 0.529, 10, 42, 26, 6, 8, 17, 24]

container = solution in my problem
```

expected result simply

```
102, 0.5, 0.591, 0.529, 10, 42, 26, 6, 8, 17, 24
```

i've try some other solution but it turn to string which is not good cause i need it in float e.g

```
In [1]:','.join( str(a) for a in tt1 )
Out[1]: '102,0.5,0.591,0.529,10,42,26,6,8,17,24'
```

plss help

Comment: isnt that the whole point of a list though? If you need to do any calculations on any item, why cant you use the list? And if you need to display it or write to a file, that has to be done in strings, so what's the issue there?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without brackets"? The brackets do not actually exist in a list, they are just part of the syntax to define a list literal in code and to print the list. Do you just want to *print* the list without the brackets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to print list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769246/pythonic-way-to-print-list-items)

Comment: `repr(tt1)[1:-1]` perhaps?

Comment: this is really what i want to do.  i want to add tt1 in another list but the thing is this just happen
    [0,
 [102, 0.5, 0.591, 0.529, 10, 42, 26, 6, 8, 17, 24],
 1,
 27,
 109,
 0.41100000000000003,
 0.308,
 0.818,
 16,
 48,
 26,
 13,
 9,
 9,
 22]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I see your problem.

> this is really what i want to do. i want to add tt1 in another list but the thing is this just happen [0, [102, 0.5, 0.591, 0.529, 10, 42, 26, 6, 8, 17, 24], 1, 27, 109, 0.41100000000000003, 0.308, 0.818, 16, 48, 26, 13, 9, 9, 22

When you add a list to another, you are simply adding the *ENTIRE* list as *one* item in the new list. Say you want to add all the values in `tt1` to a made up list, `tt2`.

```
tt1= [102, 0.5, 0.591, 0.529, 10, 42, 26, 6, 8, 17, 24]
tt2= ["some", "other", "list", 6.5, 102, True]

for item in tt1[::-1]: # we insert backwards to make it appear forwards
    tt2.insert(2, item)

print(tt2)
```

It is hard to explain, but the reason why I reverse the list temporariy (`[::-1]`) is once an item is inserted, it actually becomes the index 2. If we insert again, the previous item will become index 3 and the new item index 2  - backwards. So I reverse the list, so we're adding backwards and inserting backwards - backwards + backwards = forwards

### Output:

```
["some", "other", 102, 0.5, 0.591, 10, 42, 26, 6, 8, 17, 24, "list", 6.5, 102, True]
```

Simply replace the `tt2` with whatever list you want to add the items to.

Comment: but how can i append that in specific index list?

Comment: what i mean is this. i want to append it start in index 2 between 'other' and 'list' 
OUTPUT:["some", "other", 102, 0.5, 0.591, 0.529, 10, 42, 26, 6, 8, 17, 24,"list", 6.5, 102, True]

Comment: sorry poor internet connection btw TY