# Are there different ways to print a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python. Are there other ways to print lists for example

```
li1 = ['This is one sentence. ' 'This is another.']
print(...)
```

And then the output would be :

```
This is one sentence. This is another.
```

Comment: What is `...`? If it is `li1`, then put that instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to print list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769246/pythonic-way-to-print-list-items)

Comment: This list only has one string in it.  Are you sure that's what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack the list

```
print(*l)
```

and choose the separator in between elements.

```
print(*l, sep=', ')
```

Comment: Or even `sep=''`.

Answer (score 1):

Or try something like `print(''.join(li1))`